# Why does PHP have semaphores if it doesn't have Threads?

Tags: php, multithreading, semaphore

We have semaphores: http://php.net/manual/en/book.sem.php, but what is the use of them in PHP if we can't use Threads?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use them for inter-*process* synchronisation. `pcntl_fork` comes to mind.

Answer (score 0):

You can use them with multiprocessing, which is the original reason they exist.

However ... http://php.net/Thread

You do not need semaphores while using pthreads, additionally the current implementation of semaphores utilizes thread local storage and as such is high likely incompatible with pthreads anyway.